# My macOS hostname changed randomly should I be worried?

Tags: macos, hostname, malware

My hostname on my macOS 11.5 changed from MacBook-Pro-*username* to DESKTOP-NMO2G92 without me changing anything

Should I be worried? aka malware etc

Comment: Mine changes most times I connect to VPNs or to access points whose DHCP servers like to set hostnames.

Comment: What do you mean by "my hostname"? The local computer's "desktop" name? The name assigned by the router/gateway/DHCP server? The hostname as configured by the network configuration settings and files?